# Cargar Excel con JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, jquery

En el proyecto WEB en el que trabajo surgió la necesidad de cargar un excel a través de una interfaz de usuario , este excel al momento de cargarse debe mostrar los datos en una tabla html, sin la necesidad de que interactue con el backend.

Quisiera saber si hay alguna librería de javascript/jquery que me recomienden para poder pasar un excel (.xlsx) a una lista de objeto y viceversa.Esto para poder manejar archivos solo en el frontend

Comment: ¿Usas framework para el cliente ?

Comment: No, solo utilizo jquery en el front

Comment: Espero que pueda servir : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8238407/how-to-parse-excel-file-in-javascript-html5. Aunque lo use para otra cosa, una vez que obtengas el objeto , recorrelo

Comment: te sugiero usar esta libreria: https://redstapler.co/sheetjs-tutorial-convert-excel-html-table/

Comment: aqui tienes un eejemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/u135pbm4/

Comment: @tegito123 Investigando las opciones encontre la libreria que tu justamente me indicas estuve revisando el link que dejaste en el comentario y ya estoy trabajando en la implementacion de la funcionalidad. La libreria esta bastante interesante. Gracias !!!